# Passar valor de variavel JSP para JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

Boa tarde,

estou usando JAVA e JSP para programar.
Tenho um variável em JSP e preciso passar o valor armazenado para o codigo em JAVA.

Preciso passar a variável "X" que está em index.jsp para variável "Y" que está no main do indexJava.java

Alguám pode me ajudar?

Comment: Basta enviar os parâmetros na linha de comando que executará o programa em JAVA..

O JSP possui a classe Runtime:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec('aqui vc executa o comando.. como se estivesse num terminal, no command prompt'). Mas logicamente, não preciso comentar que o programa em JAVA deve estar pronto para receber os parâmetros.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de como você está passando do JSP para o Java.

Se for uma simples chamada de função entre <% %> ou ${}, é uma passagem de parâmetro normal.

Se for um *forward* use o escopo *request*.

Se for um *redirect* use o escopo *session*.

Se você der mais detalhes de como está estruturado seu código, posso melhorar esta resposta.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServletDemo extends HttpServlet{

    private String y; 

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            y = request.getParameter("x");
        }
}
```

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html >
        <head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>

              X : <input type="text" value="" id="x" />

        </body>
    </html>
```